# Know any Bible verses on 'faith,' 'knowledge' or what it means to 'believe'?

Tags: faith, reference-request, wisdom

I was assigned to present a paper on epistemology, which is the philosophy of truth, knowledge and belief, and to convey it on the terms of my judgment. I am blessed to have a professor who encourages his students to freely express their opinion, and this is what I intend to do.

Do you know any good verses on 'faith' and 'knowledge' and what it means to 'believe?'

Thank you!

Ava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hebrews 11: 1 says "Now faith is being sure of what we hope for and certain of what we do not see."**

This is probably one of the most fundamental verses you can quote when asked about faith. It is the most obvious and clear definition of what it means to believe something especially God.

Knowledge is pretty much the same as faith. We all know the color of the shirt we are wearing today; and we know it is either red, or blue because we believe it is. You might say, we do not just believe it, because we actually 'see' it, but have you considered asking: What if red isn't really red? or color isn't really color? We 'know' things because we 'believe' they are.

We are certain of something, like a God or a supreme being because we 'believe' there is a God, we  perceive God, through nature, through His works, through the emotions we feel about Him, and that collection of perception becomes the very foundation of 'knowledge' of God.

PS: Faith is like eating in a fast-food restaurant, you'll never know how it was made, but you believe it's safe, and you eat it anyway.

Comment: I very much appreciate this answer! It is clarifying and covers nearly all of what I have been learning in my philosophy class this past week with a sweet and simple Bible using answer! Thank you!

Comment: If everything requires for us to believe then we live in a world that means much more than to just simply exist; we are here to believe.  
Would it be correct, in your opinion, to say that we were all born to believe; that life is all about believing? I mean, if this were not the case then, we would never drive into town because, who knows, it might not be there anymore! Or reach down to pet our cat assuming that he still likes us when really, he might not! I know this is turning into a philosophy question, but I had to ask. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes you can say that, but some might argue with you about being 'born to believe' as others view this differently. But an answer coming from a Christian point of view, yes. We were born to believe God, believe that He exists and that He is in control of everything he created. And about believing in general, still, everything is there because we believe it is. So yeah.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this for me! It is so compelling, the simplicity of this concept to think that our one mission (among others) is to simply believe. Thanks again!

Comment: i thought you accepted this answer? xD haha

Comment: Yes, haha. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Hebrews 11;6  But  without  faith  it  is impossible  to  please  him;  for he  that  cometh  to  God  must  believe  he  is,  and  that  he  is  a  rewarder  of  them  that  diligently  seek  him.

James 2;14-26  What  doth  it  profit,  my  brethren,  though  a  man  say  he  hath  faith,  and  have  not  works?  If  a  brother  or  sister  be  naked  and  be  destitute  of  daily  food,  And  one  of  you  say  unto them,  Depart  in  peace,  be  ye  warmed  and  filled;  notwithstanding  ye  give  them  not  those  things  which  are  needful  to  the  body;  what  doth  it  profit?  Even  so  faith,  if  it  hath  not  works  is  dead,  being  alone.  Yea  a  man  say,  Thou  has  faith,  and  I  have  works:  shew  me  thy  faith  without  thy  works,  and  I  will  shew  thee  my  faith  by  my  works.  Thou  believest  that  there  is  one  God;  thou  doest  well:  the  devils  also  believe,  and  tremble.  But  wilt  thou  know,  O  vain  man,  that  faith  without  works  is  dead?  Was  not  Abraham  our  father  justified  by  works,  when  had  offered  Isaac  his  son upon the  alter?  Seest  thou  how  faith  wrought  with  his  works,  and  by  works  was  faith  made  perfect?  And  the  scripture  was  fulfilled  which  saith,  Abraham  believed  God  and  it  was  imputed  unto  him  for  righteouness,  and  he  was  called  a  friend  of  God.  ye  see  then  how  that  by  works  a  man  is  justified,  and  not  by  faith  only.  Likewise  Rahab  the  harlot  justified  by works,  when  she  had  received  messengers,  and  had  sent  them  out  another  way?  For  as  the  body  without  spirit  is  dead,  so  faith  without  works  is  dead  also.

Faith  without  action  is  self-deception.